# The use of 'how could ...' in past tense situations

Tags: past-tense, rhetorical-devices, could

A grammatical issue has been bugging me for some time, and I just can't seem to wrap my head around it. If I'm writing in the past tense and questioning the ability to do something or the possibility of something that happened earlier, can I simply use 'how could ...'? For example:

> I was under so much emotional stress at the time. I really wanted to tell you my feelings. But how could I tell you when you were never around?

Or, would I have to write:

> But how could I have told you when you were never around?

Similarly, would one write:

> You were a terrible person back then, but I forgave you for everything you'd done. How couldn't I forgive you?

It's clear that everything is taking place in the past in both cases, so it's impossible for a reader to think that 'could' in this case has to do with a future possibility.

What's the 'rule' regarding questions beginning with 'how could'? Does 'could' -- in contexts where it's completely clear we're dealing with the past tense -- denote the simple past, and 'could ... have' a more distant past? For instance, would it be correct to write:

> But the Romans couldn't defeat the Amazons. How could they defeat such a powerful people? And how could the Greeks before them have beaten them?

Is my understanding correct? I'm totally confused right now, so any clarification would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's just you. I think those sentences are grammatical but find them a bit awkward. They make me think of *if a lion could talk, we could not understand him*, which shows that it's not just a case of past vs future possibility. I use workarounds, e.g. *if a lion could talk, we would not be able to understand him*, *there was no way for them to defeat such a powerful people* etc. I actually think *there was no way they could defeat such a powerful people* works in your sentence, which may cast some light on what makes the original awkward.

Comment: I've voted to close (lack of research).  If you check a dictionary and still have trouble, please do edit your question to show us where you got stuck. // *Could* has two different meanings.  One is the past tense of *can* and the other is a conditional.  If the sentence says, "How can we accomplish that?" and you shift it into the past tense, you get, "How could we accomplish that?" which is an analytical, maybe rhetorical question.  A shocked "How could you think it is/was okay to do that?" is conditional. // The forgive sentence works better as *How could I not forgive you?

Comment: Thanks, @minty. I guess a more concise way of putting my question is, what differentiates the use of 'how could ...' sentences from 'how could ... have' ones? Is it ability vs possibility, or does it have to do with tenses? Would it be correct to say, 'I didn't lie. How could I lie? And how could my great-great-grandparents *have* lied?' Or would we simply use 'could' in both cases? My instinct tells me we need to differentiate the tenses here, and I don't see how we can do that without using 'could have'.

Comment: The context usually disambiguates them, not the grammar.

Comment: In casual speech, we tend to avoid complex tenses like "How could I have" when we can just say "How could I". The intent is usually clear.

Comment: Modals behave strangely with tenses – I’m not sure you can carry the usual tense system over. What tense is used in *how could I have told you*, for example?  It’s not just a modal plus the present perfect, or we’d say *how could he has told you*. It’s an infinitive plus a past participle, and you don’t get that construction where there’s no modal verb, so I think you have to look at these constructions on their own terms.

Comment: I’d say *[subj] could* can mean *it would be possible for [s] to* or *it was possible for [s] to*, whereas *[s] could have* corresponds to *it would have been possible for [s] to* or *it is possible that [s] did* (*he could have escaped through the window*). On that basis, *how could my g-g-grandparents lie* could mean *how would it be possible for them to lie* or *how was it possible for them to lie*, whereas *how could they have lied* means *how would it have been possible for them to lie* or *how is it possible that they did lie = how is it possible that they lied*.

Comment: That means that they are both correct – one is equivalent to your g-g-grandparents saying to each other *how can we lie?* and the other is equivalent to them saying *how could we lie?* In reality of course it’s more complicated – constructions with *could* are not completely equivalent to constructions with *would*, otherwise *if a lion could talk, we could not understand him* would be just as natural as *if we took that flight, we could spend a day in Paris*.